# Getting height of the window (without scroll)

Tags: jquery, css, prototypejs

I have a google maps on a page, written in mostly php prototype and jquery.

I want map to be responsive and i managed to set it's width correctly. But couldn't handle hight problem.

You see

```
jQuery(window).height();
```

returns height of the page that's good, but not what I wanted. As you can see in image, there is a scrollbar on right and it gives me the height of the whole page. I want to get the value of the height of the screen(without scroll, viewport), how can i do that?

[image]

Edit: `var x               = jQuery(window).height();`

```
    alert(x);
```

returns 961 so i believe the value of i want is something like 800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i've come up with is to define a css class wrapping the map.

```
.gm_responsive {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 68%;
padding-top: 45px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

}
I believe the key is

```
padding-bottom: 68%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out these Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/corinne/pKUzU/

```
iframe {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto; /*IE8 bug fix*/
vertical-align: middle
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var weight = window.innerHeight;
```

which gives the current view-port height.

Comment: Nope still returns 961px

Answer (score 0):

What you want to get is the viewport height (the view in the page) and this is what $(window).height() returns.
Do you want to get the height of the container ? (just get it)

We need to see your probleme, please give use a link or make a JSFiddle.

Comment: I want to get the height of the viewport. For example whole page's height is 961px but viewport should be like 800px so i want to get the value of viewport

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
var dimensions = document.viewport.getDimensions();
height = dimensions.height;
```

this is part of the core PrototypeJS not jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript to get viewport dimensions excluding scrollbar size.

```js
document.documentElement.clientHeight; // answer that OP wants, get height viewport without scrollbar
document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```